# Can the GAE Python documentation be downloaded for offline reading?

Tags: google-app-engine

IIRC the GAE [downloads page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) used to have a separate link for the documentation, but I don't see one now.  Is it possible to download the Python documentation for faster, local access?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Jan Killian [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/mj_VA3UCkD8/UnhmEC-tDnEJ), there is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8654) to get the offline docs downloadable and updated which you can star, as I did, to help push its priority.

In the meantime, I use Jan's approach in that post of mirroring the site with httrack. So if i ran it in directory '/home/yuvilio/app/docs'

```
$ httrack -N100 -%k https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/
```

It would make the documentation available via browser at file url `file:///home/yuvilio/apps/docs/appengine/docs/python/index.html`

For better stylesheet setup, I decided to have a virtual host on my local web server point to the root directory ( `/home/yuvilio/apps/docs/appengine/docs/python` ) and have the _static/ directory there with the expected stylesheets in the css/ directory in it. That is, I created a simple virtual host on my local Apache server and pointed it at the directory for the DocumentRoot. I then ran a simple search and replace script on the files to change all `https://developers.google.com` to the my vhosts's ServerName (I called it `http://developers.google.dev` ) and got styles that way. I could then browse the documentation through `http://developers.google.dev/index.html` which I ended up switching to .

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the full AppEngine documentation using this command

```
wget  --recursive  --no-clobber  --page-requisites --html-extension  --convert-links  --restrict-file-names=windows --no-parent      https://developers.google.com/appengine/
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check if this is exactly the same documentation that google is serving on app engine web page, but the app engine svn has documentation directories that at least look like the web pages by browsing the source:

```
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/docs/
```

You can check out this with an svn client.

Comment: That documentation dates from Dec 13, 2011. It's not the same as what's at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/.

Comment: That directory was [removed](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/detail?r=346)